# Does it matter if sound is produced via a sound card or via a small cd player built in the CD-ROM drive in DOSBox?

Tags: windows-vista, compact-disc, dosbox

I tried to load in DOSBox the PLAYCD utility.

It worked with audio CD but it was silent. The manual for DOSBox recommends me to install Windows Vista (to enable ioctl access).

ut is this reasonable if the software which I want to use is based on built-in CD player in CD-ROM drive?

Comment: Many old CD drives had a physical connector which would connect to your sound card and transmit analogue audio. The software would simply tell the drive to "play" the audio CD which would then be fed through your sound card and out to your speakers. There was no digital audio coming into the playing software at that point, hence no audio in DOSBox. Without that connection your system literally needs to *read* the audio CD properly as if it were a data disk.

Comment: @Mokubai♦
Thank you very much. Your answer was thorough and informative. And nobody downvoted my question!

Answer (score 1):

For playing CD audio via DOSBox it's highly recommended to convert your CD to an image: either ISO or CUE+BIN, CUE+MP3, CUE+OGG, CUE+FLAC (DOSBox Staging), or CUE+OPUS (DOSBox Staging). Once you'll have that, you will be able to mount the CD image in DOSBox using `imgmount` utility.

Reference in DOSBox Staging manual: https://github.com/dosbox-staging/dosbox-staging/blob/master/README#L784

Comment: Would this then allow DOSBox to play the audio on the CD without it being silent due to older systems simply playing audio directly from the CD?

Comment: After you make a CD image and imgmount it inside DOSBox Staging, the audio will be decoded and mixed by DOSBox internal mixer - all audio will be coming out of the emulator. You can even change the volume of every channel inside DOSBox separately (so e.g. make emulated CD-DA louder and make emulated SoundBlaster quieter) - that's `mixer` command.